# Alfresco wsdl access issue, SOAP failed

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, alfresco

I have setup Alfresco on my local system.. I am trying to use `AlfrescoPHPSDK-PHPLibrary-0.1` to get tickets. I am trying the examples provided in the package but it gives me following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL
: Couldn't load from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService?wsdl' 
: failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService?wsdl" in D:\wamp\www\alfrescophp\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php:36
```

- I have installed Alfresco on my local PC
- I am able to open and login Alfresco from browser
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api` this URL accepted same credential.
- But when I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService?wsdl` It ask me `username/Password` and not accepting the credentials I used for Alfresco.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using CMIS? Only it's much better supported!

Comment: Are you sure it's /api/ the /api/ url is used for the new Public api and the old WSDL is now /soapapi/
Btw on which version of Alfresco are you on? And you probably should know in the new Alfresco 5.0 the old SOAP API is removed, so better to switch to CMIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was answered on alfresco forum that paths for SOAP API has been moved for alfresco 4.2.d.

Now instead of being `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api` the soap services resides at `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/soapapi`.

Refrence: https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Content_Management_Web_Services